# Internal Google Apps emails being marked as spam

Tags: google-apps-email, spam-prevention

Today a bunch of users have complained about internal emails ending up in their spam boxes in Gmail. Especially when they send it to the email group.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you have configured your [SPF records](https://support.google.com/a/answer/178723?hl=en&ref_topic=2759192) properly.

To create an SPF record for a domain:

> 1. Log in to the administrative console for your domain.
> 2. Locate the page from which you can update the DNS records. You may need to enable advanced settings.
> 3. Create a TXT record containing this text: `v=spf1 include:_spf.google.com ~all`. 
>       Publishing an SPF record that uses `-all` instead of `~all` may result in delivery problems. See Google IP address ranges for details
>      about the addresses for the Google Apps mail servers.
>
>    To authorize an additional mail server, add the server's IP address
>      before just before the `~all` argument using the format `ip4:address` or
>      `ip6:address`. (See Sender Policy Framework for more details on the SPF
>      format.)
> 4. If your registrar also requires a host setting (such as @), see the TXT records for specific domain providers list for precise
>      instructions.
> 5. Save your changes. Keep in mind that changes to DNS records may take up to 48 hours to propagate throughout the Internet.

Also, you can adjust your Spam filter settings by following Google's tutorial [here](https://support.google.com/a/answer/2368132?hl=en).